# How to set GoogleApiClient api key programmatically

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

This is how I set the Places API key in AndroidManifest.xml
I was wondering is there is a way to set it programmatically like in MapView:

```
mMapView = new MapView(this, mapApiKey);
```

Edit: 
My goal is to fetch the key from my backend, so I need to set it at a later stage and not on app launch.

Comment: add key to string.xml and use from that in menifest or any other places.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal OP wants to set it dynamically not any hardcoded value.@Peter I don't think it's possible.